# Why is the result of a bitwise shift unrecoverable if there is a mathematical equivalent of the same operation?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Take for example the number 91. That number in binary is 1011011. If you shift that number to the right by 5 bits, you would get 2 (10 in binary). According to a google search, bit shifting to the left or right by a certain amount of bits is the same as multiplying or dividing the number by 2 to the power of the number of bits to be shifted, respectively. so to get from 91 to 2 by bit shifting, the equation would look like this: `91 / 2^5`, which is also `91 / 32`. Now, of course if you did that in your calculator, there would be some decimal values, which aren't included when bit shifting. The resulting 2 is actually `2.84357`. I'm sure you know that if you do a certain operation on a number and then you do the inverse, the result would be what you had in the first place. So does decimal precision have something to do with this?

Comment: I mean, technically, if you took the binary number `1011011`, and shifted all the digits right by one place, you would get `101101.1`, which is `45.5` in decimal. However, since computers don't store that one-half's place (the `.1` in binary), it gets dropped, so `91 >> 1` is `45` on a computer. Similarly, if you took decimal `91` and shifted the digits right, you'd get `9.1`, but you'd be forced to drop that `.1` if you could only represent whole numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mathematical equivalent of shifting to the right... **and the mathematical operation is UNRECOVERABLE**.

You seem to think that shifting to the right is:

> bit shifting to the left or right by a certain amount of bits is the same as multiplying or dividing the number by 2

This is what you will hear people casually say, but it is only half right. As it it is not **the same** but only **similar**.

The correct statement is:

> shifting a base-2 number one digit to the right is THE SAME as dividing by two in the integer domain

If you have an integer calculator, if you did `91/32` you will get `2`. You will not get ANY decimal point because we are operating in the integer domain.

For real numbers, the equivalent operation is:

```
FLOOR(91/32)
```

Which is also unrecoverable because it also results in `2`.

The lesson here is **be careful when listening to what people CASUALLY say**. Casual speech is often imprecise and assumes the listener is familiar with the subject. You need to dig deeper what the statement is **actually** trying to say.

As for why it is unrecoverable? Division of integers give two results: the **quotient** (which is the main result) and the **remainder**. When we divide `91` by `32` we are doing this:

```
       2
    _____
 32 ) 91
      64
      __
      27
```

So we get the result of `2` and a remainder of `27`. The reason you can't get `91` by multiplying `2*32` is because we threw away the remainder.

You can get the result back if you saved the remainder. However, calculating the remainder is not a matter of simple shifts. Here's an example of how to make it reversable in C:

```
int test () {
    int a = 91;
    int b = 32;
    int result;
    int remainder;

    result    = a / b; // result will be 2
    remainder = a % b; // remainder will be 27

    return (result * b) + remainder; // returns 91
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only recover the result of an operation if it has a 1-1 mapping between the inputs and outputs, i.e. it has an [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function). But not all mathematical functions have an inverse function

For example if `f(x) = x >> n` with `>>` is the shift operator then it'll be equivalent to

> **f(x) = ⌊x/2<sup>n</sup>⌋**

with **⌊ ⌋** being the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). Since there are **many inputs that lead to the same output**, the relationship isn't 1-1 and there can't be an inverse function for it. This function works the same for both signed and unsigned right shift:

```
91 >> 5 == floor(91.0/32.0) == 2
-91 >> 5 == floor(-91.0/32.0) == -3
```

---

Similarly for an unsigned left shift function `g(x) = x << n` then the equivalent is

> **g(x) = (x * 2<sup>n</sup>) mod 2<sup>N</sup>**

with N being the size in bits of x, because integer math in hardware, C and many other languages always reduce modulo 2<sup>N</sup> due to the limit of register size and the use of two's complement. And it's clear that the modulo function also isn't invertible/recoverable. The signed left shift is almost the same with some small modifications